# vline legends not showing on geom_histogram type plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm struggling getting the legends for two vline elements showing on an histogram. I set the show_guide=T on the vline elements to force the legend to show, but it does not help.

I suspect that this is due to the geom_histogram plot showing only one series of data which. But not sure how to force the legend to show first place.

```
ggplot(mttr, aes(x=Resolution.Time)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=0.5) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean(Resolution.Time, na.rm=T)),
             color="red", linetype="dashed", size=1, show_guide=T) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=median(Resolution.Time, na.rm=T)),
             color="green", linetype="dashed", size=1, show_guide=T) + 
  xlim(c(0,40)) +
  xlab("Resolution Time (days)") # + theme(legend.position=c(1,0), legend.justification=c(1,0))
```

[image: histogram with mean and median vlines]

Is there a way to force the legend to show (for vlines), even if the histogram does not have an aesthetic fill ?

I already tried a number of potential solutions found on stackoverflow but without success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: add a reproducible example. we don't have access to your data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Method 1: Manually map colors

- Place `colour=<your label>` inside the `aes` function for `geom_vline`
- Add `scale_color_manual` and correctly map your labels to the colors that you want

Example:

```
mttr <- data.frame(Resolution.Time = rexp(1000, 0.25))

ggplot(mttr, aes(x=Resolution.Time)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=0.5) +

  # Notice that I have color = "Mean" inside aes
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean(Resolution.Time, na.rm=T), color = "Mean"),
             linetype="dashed", size=1, show_guide=T) +

  # Here I have have color = "Median" inside aes
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=median(Resolution.Time, na.rm=T), color = "Median"),
             linetype="dashed", size=1, show_guide=T) + 

  xlim(c(0,40)) +
  xlab("Resolution Time (days)") +

  # Here I map my labels, "Mean" and "Median", to their colors
  # The legend title is "Statistics"
  scale_color_manual("Statistics", values = c("Mean" = "red", "Median" = "green"))
```

[image]

#### Method 2: Create a separate data frame to plot your vertical lines

This method scales more nicely, and involves a single `geom_vline` instead of several.

- Make a `data.frame` for the vertical lines that you want to plot, with columns describing the labels and the values
- Have a single `geom_vline` that maps the `xintercept` to the values and the `color` to the labels
- Optionally, control the colors by choosing an appropriate `scale_color_*()`

Example:

```
# Create a data frame with two columns, a label and a value
vlines = data.frame("Statistic" = c("Mean", "Median"),
                    "Value" = c(mean(mttr$Resolution.Time), median(mttr$Resolution.Time)),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Plot
ggplot(mttr, aes(x=Resolution.Time)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=0.5) +

  # Here we have a single geom_vline call
  # Map the xintercept to Value, color to Statistic
  # Specify data = vlines outside the aes function
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = Value, color = Statistic),
             linetype = "dashed", size = 1, show_guide = TRUE, data = vlines) +

  xlim(c(0,40)) +
  xlab("Resolution Time (days)") # + scale_color_*() to change your colors
```

[image]

Comment: Both methods work great, second one is excellent, elegant and scalable. Thank you very much for your very valuable reply.